# Fullcalendar JSON Encode and Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, fullcalendar

I've got a calendar showing on a page but I can't for the life of me get the thing working. I'm making an array within my controller, passing it to the view json_encoded but the fullcalendar doesn't want to pick the array up and pop it into the calendar. Please see my code below:

**HomeController**

```
    public function calendar_feed(){

  return response()->json(
  [
    'title' => 'Matts Booking',
    'start' => '2018-01-01T22:40',
    'end' => '2019-01-01T23:40'
  ], 200
  );

}
```

**Fullcalendar Function**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ( $ ) { 

  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
    },
    editable: false,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    firstDay: 1,
    eventLimit: false, // allow "more" link when too many events
    navLinks: true,
    events: '{{ route("calendar_feed") }}'
  });
    }( jQuery ));
</script>
```

**What the array is sending**

```
{"title":"Matts Booking","start":"2018-01-01T22:40","end":"2019-01-01T23:40"}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the name of the property `events` and [array example](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/events-array), looks like it needs an array of it, so add an extra pair of square brackets:

```
public function calendar_feed(){
  return response()->json([[
      'title' => 'Matts Booking',
      'start' => '2018-01-01T22:40',
      'end' => '2019-01-01T23:40'
   ]], 200
  );
}
```

Now you return an array of objects with single element.

Comment: Ivan, if I could kiss you I would! Thank you it's worked perfectly!